# Activate both, WinCache and OpCache for php 5.6 to improve performance?

Tags: performance, iis-8.5, php-5.6, opcache, wincache

We're running a typo3-website on Windows Server using IIS 8.5 and php 5.6.15 via FastCGI. To improve performance and reduce db-load, we enabled the WinCache-Extension, because of it's **UserCache** capabilities. WinCache's **OpCache** is disabled, since it is stated as deprecated and **OpCache** is already bundled with php.

- Does it make any sense for the purpose of performance, to enable WinCache-**FileCache** too, besides php's **OpCode-Cache**?
- Is there any order, these caches are used, or will these cache-types compete against each other?
- Should I better completely disable OpCache, in case of using WinCache?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You find an answer? I'm in the same doubt...

Comment: @ar099968: unfortunately not. We decided to drop WinCache since it caused an 500 from time to time, taking the site down for a few minutes. We tried to reduce statements against the db and stuck to the built in OpCode cache and native typo3-caching systems. It's a good solution so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinCache's file cache will cache any file opened via PHP's stream APIs.  This includes the script files, as well as any file opened using the stream I/O APIs. 
So, yes, there is some benefit to having WinCache's file cache enabled, even though you have the Zend Opcache enabled.